# Surface mount ceiling fan

Tags: ceiling-fan

I have a Tri-State home with a center beam extending from one gable end of the house to the other at the peak.  The beam is completely exposed in the living room.  I installed a ceiling fan with light twenty years ago and now the unit has failed.  I need to install a new one.  I have surface mount wall switch and conduit going up to the beam where the old fan was.  I have no electrical box, the wires were enclosed in the canopy of the fan unit.  Is this okay to do.  I installed this myself twenty years ago and the guy from the building center where I purchased everything said that was okay.  I am now having my doubts.  What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

## Stop being a cheapskate and get a box, will ya?

What you need is a surface-mounted ceiling fan box, either of the [saddle](http://www.menards.com/main/maintenance-repair-operations/lighting-electrical/wiring-connecting/electrical-boxes/pvc/carlon-16-cu-in-saddle-type-ceiling-fan-box/p-2180328-c-6431.htm?tid=37946329057834987) or the [pancake](http://www.menards.com/main/maintenance-repair-operations/lighting-electrical/wiring-connecting/electrical-boxes/pvc/carlon-8-cu-in-shallow-ceiling-fan-box/p-1517781-c-6431.htm?tid=37946329057834987) types.  Wiring a fan without a box is a great way to drop a ceiling fan on the head of an unsuspecting guest, as well as a fire hazard if a splice ever fails!  Just make sure the box you get is rated for the fan load you have...

Comment: No pancake boxes! Those things don't always meet box fill requirements, and may or may not be rated to support the weight of a ceiling fan. The [catalog (PDF)(page 8)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.carlonsales.com/techinfo/brochures/electrical/Zip%2520Boxes_2B1.pdf&ved=0CEUQFjADahUKEwjXw-7g1dTHAhVFPj4KHWacAyY&usg=AFQjCNHFiwNQA-l3rvxNTKxLTKolF6002A&sig2=ScoTcoOKGo2sMGSbj8Gi8w) lists that pancake box at 35 lbs fan weight, and 50 lbs fixture weight.

Comment: @Tester101 yeah, whatever box he gets needs to be rated to handle the weight of the fan.

Comment: @Tester101 -- also, does wiring space provided by a fixture count towards box fill space?

Comment: If the volume is marked on the canopy, then it can be used (314.16(A)). However, I doubt you'll find a canopy with a volume marked on it.

Comment: @Tester101 -- that's odd that they don't, I suppose -- penny-pinchers at work?

Comment: Not really that odd. If they wanted the canopy to be used as a junction box, they'd have to have it tested as such. I'm sure most of them aren't make of thick enough, or the proper material to pass.